# Can I use '$set' on embedded document when use variable as filed name in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to use '$set' to update an embedded document, but the field is a variable.

Say I have a document like:

```
{'_id': ObjectID,
 'people': {
     'A': {'age': 20}
 }
}
```

Now I want to add a new person to `people`. I can use `$set: {'people.B':{'age': 25}`, but what if the name(instead B) is a variable?

I am using Node.js 5.1 and 'mongodb' driver.

Comment: It sounds like `people` should be an array.  Is there a reason why you are explicitly labeling the objects 'A', 'B', etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your query dynamically using the `[]` operator.

```js
var b = 'B';
var update = {};
update['people.' + b] = { 'age': 25 };
db.collection.update({}, { '$set': update })
```