# MongoDB: querying using a string reference as a key

Tags: mongodb, reference, key

Does anyone know if there's a way to use a reference to a string in a mongo query, instead of using the string directly in it?

i.e. I want to do this:

```
key = "id";
value = "12345";
collection("accounts").find({key: value});
```

Instead of this:

```
collection("accounts").find({"id": "12345"});
```

Comment: I specifically want to know how to do this for the primary key - i.e. collection("accounts").find({"_id": ObjectId("12345")});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use '$set' on embedded document when use variable as filed name in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000536/can-i-use-set-on-embedded-document-when-use-variable-as-filed-name-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

Use the bracket notation to create the query object:

```
key = "_id";
value = "57ffe131b0b79719a0db75d8";
query = {};
query[key] = ObjectId(value);
collection("accounts").find(query);
```